# Hash Key and Value in Perl

Tags: perl

I have the question in Perl:Read a series of last names and phone numbers from the given input. The names and numbers should be separated by a comma. Then print the names and numbers alphabetically according to last name. Use hashes.

```
#!usr/bin/perl
my %series = ('Ashok','4365654435' 'Ramnath','4356456546' 'Aniketh','4565467577');
while (($key, $value) = each(sort %series))
{
 print $key.",".$value."\n";
}
```

I am not getting the output. Where am I going wrong? Please help. Thanks in advance

```
#!usr/bin/perl
my %series = ('Ashok','4365654435' 'Ramnath','4356456546' 'Aniketh','4565467577');
print $_.",".$series{$_}."\n" for sort keys %series;
```

If I execute any of the above 2 programs, I get the same output as:

```
String found where operator expected at line 2, near "'4365654435' 'Ramnath'" (Missing operator before  'Ramnath'?)
String found where operator expected at line 2, near "'4356456546' 'Aniketh'" (Missing operator before  'Aniketh'?)
syntax error at line 2, near "'4365654435' 'Ramnath'"
Execution aborted due to compilation errors
```

But according to the question, I think I cannot store the input as `my %series = ('Ashok','4365654435','Ramnath','4356456546','Aniketh','4565467577');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`each` only operates on hashes. You can't use `sort` like that, it sorts lists not hashes.

Your loop could be:

```
foreach my $key (sort keys %series) {
  print $key.",".$series{$key}."\n";
}
```

Or in shorthand:

```
print $_.",".$series{$_}."\n" for sort keys %series;
```

Answer (score 2):

In your hash declaration you have:

```
my %series = ('Ashok','4365654435' 'Ramnath','4356456546' 'Aniketh','4565467577');
```

This is generating the warnings.

A hash is simply an even list of scalars. Therefore, you have to put a comma between each pair:

```
my %series = ('Ashok','4365654435', 'Ramnath','4356456546', 'Aniketh','4565467577');
             #                    ^---                    ^---
```

If you want visual distinction between the pairs, you can use the `=>` operator. This behaves the same as the comma. Additionaly, if the left hand side is a legal bareword, it is viewed as a quoted string. Therefore, we could write any of these:

```
# it is just a comma after all, with autoquoting
my %series = (Ashok => 4365654435 => Ramnath => 4356456546 => Aniketh => 4565467577);

# using it as a visual "pair" constructor
my %series = ('Ashok'=>'4365654435', 'Ramnath'=>'4356456546', 'Aniketh'=>'4565467577');

# as above, but using autoquoting. Numbers don't have to be quoted.
my %series = (
   Ashok   => 4365654435,
   Ramnath => 4356456546,
   Aniketh => 4565467577,
);
```

This last solution is the best. The last coma is optional, but I consider it good style—it makes it easy to add another entry. You can use autoquoting whenever the bareword on the left would be a legal variable name. E.g. `a_bc => 1` is valid, but `a bc => 1` is not (whitespace is not allowed in variable names), and `+/- => 1` is not allowed (reserved characters). However `Ünıçøðé => 1` is *allowed* when your source code is encoded in UTF-8 and you `use uft8` in your script.

Answer (score 1):

Besides what amonand Mat said, I'd like to notice other issues in your code:

- your **shebang** is wrong it should be `#!/usr/bin/perl` - notice the first `/`
- you don't have `use strict;` and `use warnings;` in your code - although this is not strictly a mistake, I consider this to be an issue. Those 2 commands will save you from a lot of trouble later on.

PS: you have to use commas between your number and names also, not only between names and numbers - you have to, because otherwise you get a compile error

Comment: I think it is a mistake not to use strict and warnings, especially when trying to learn perl.

Comment: My recommendation is to always `use strict;` and `use warnings;`; until you know exactly why it is recommended.